# How do I find the inverse of T?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Would I transform the T into a matrix of some form?

Comment: Represent linear transformation $T$ with respect to a basis of $P_3$?  Have you tried this with the usual basis, $\{1,x,x^2\}$ ?

Comment: It should be $T^{-1}(ax^2+bx+c) = ( -cx^2+(a+5c)x+2a+b+5c )$.

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a basis of $P_3$ -- the standard one will work well enough -- and apply $T$ to each vector in the standard basis. That will give you some polynomials, which you can represent using the standard basis of your target space (here $P_3$ again) and put as the columns of the matrix.

So, the standard basis of $P_3$ is $\{1,x,x^2\}$, find $T(1)$ and put that as the first column of a matrix, similarly for $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$.